# How do I get translated label for a base field definition?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

As mentioned [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/251843/88237) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2019-09-17/get-translated-field-label), there is a (complicated) way, to get can get a translated labels for bundle fields.

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;

// Override language before loading field configuration.
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguage('fr');
\Drupal::languageManager()->setConfigOverrideLanguage($langu‌​age);

// $entity_type, $bundle, $field.
$field_info = FieldConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'bundle', 'myField'); 

$label = $field_info->getLabel();
```

I however cannot find a way, how to achieve this for base fields. A hack like supplying a(any) bundle also leads to no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible translation methods for a base field, interface translation and configuration translation.

Base fields are defined in code and translated by t(), which gets the translatable string from the core interface translation table.

```
$translatableMarkup = t($label, [], ["langcode" => $langcode]);
//optionally, render to string
$translatedLabel = $translatableMarkup->render();
```

If a base field override exists in configuration, then it contains a translatable label:

```
// Override language before loading field configuration.
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguage('fr');
\Drupal::languageManager()->setConfigOverrideLanguage($langu‌​age);

$field_override = BaseFieldOverride::loadByName('entity_type', 'bundle', 'myField');
if ($field_override) {
  $label = $field_override->getLabel();
}
```