# How do I retrieve a plugin block field's translated value?

Tags: 8, blocks, i18n-l10n

I created a module that installs a block with some fields when installed. I added a schema file, and altered the `blockSubmit()` function so that the translation is saved in the schema.

Here is my module.schema.yml:

```
block.settings.worldwide:
  type: block_settings
  label: 'Worldwide'
  mapping:
    overtitle:
      type: label
      label: 'Overtitle'
```

Here is the `blockSubmit()` function from my Block plugin:

```
public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::blockSubmit($form, $form_state);
    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    $block_name = $this->getPluginId();

    $this->blockConfigFactory->setBlockConfig($block_name, 'overtitle', $values['overtitle']);
    $this->setConfigurationValue('overtitle', $values['overtitle']);
}
```

When saving, I have no error, and can translate the field, which will keep the translation when updated. So everything seems to work. Additionnally, the website displays correctly what I saved for the default language.

Now, let's say that the default language is english and the alternative is french. My issue is that if I set the website in french, the default (english) value will keep displaying.

However, I can't figure out a way to displayed the saved translation when I want to look at the block in a language that has the block's translation saved. I have no idea where to look, and can't seem to find relevant stuff on internet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at this [thread on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2993984) and the module [translated_config](https://www.drupal.org/project/translated_config).

Comment: "Now, let's say that the default language is english and the alternative is french. My issue is that if I set the website in french, the default (english) value will keep displaying. " Displaying where? The block form or the rendered block?

Comment: My rendered block, in my template

Comment: OK, the translation form is not built by the plugin, Drupal builds it independently for all configuration values which are translatable according to the schema. You can also translate configuration objects in exported yaml files, which I think would be a good starting point for debugging.

Comment: Is it possible retrieve the saved translation from the configuration ? Like, loading "blocks.settings.worldwide"? I tried to do that but I couldn't find a way to retrieve my data

Comment: Yes, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251841/how-do-i-get-a-field-label-in-different-languages. But the rendered block should do this automatically, configuration overrides work system wide without any specific code you need for example for content entities.

Answer (score 0):

Little did I know, the translation was correctly loaded, but not used in the twig files. Both the fields' `content` and `configuration` were loaded, were `content` was *ie* an image and a link, and `configuration` the field's translation.

Somehow, still, the configuration needed several cache rebuilds to show up, but then went ok and kept being updated if I made any modifications.

The twig files were using variables such as `{{ content['field_worldwide_text'] }}`, so I needed it to use `config[]` instead.

Additional notes for future self, here is how to load `content` and `configuration`:

```
$content = $this->blockConfigFactory->getBlockConfig($this->getPluginId());
$config = $this->getConfiguration();
```